# Install Natty VM on Lucid host using vm builder

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtual-machines, vmbuilder

I'm trying to create new VM using vmbuilder:

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --suite=natty (...)
```

But i get following error:

```
VMBuilder.exception.VMBuilderUserError: Invalid suite: "natty". Valid suites are: dapper gutsy hardy intrepid jaunty karmic lucid maverick
```

Is there any way to workaround this (i.e. by installing vmbuilder from natty)?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of vmbuilder does not support natty yet.
I'm using the 0.12.4.r455 from the daily ppa, but even this version does not support natty yet.

You could try backporting the vm-builder version from natty, but I don't if that would work.

Answer (score -1):

you can use --suite=natty option. Make sure to give valid mirror to retrieve the release. i.e. use the option --mirror=http://your-mirror-url/ubuntu/

Comment: doesn't work for me: VMBuilder.exception.VMBuilderUserError: Invalid suite: "natty". Valid suites are: dapper gutsy hardy intrepid jaunty karmic lucid maverick. Of course i have valid mirror.